# While building for tvOS, no library for this platform was found

Tags: swift, tvos, starscream, swiftprotobuf

I have integrated two third party libraries into the tvOS project.  I have no clue why I am getting this error.

My Xcode version is 14.0.1.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44irJ.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8CY4.png]

Comment: `s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'` as I saw from the podspec file starscream has an support for tvOS but with min version of 9, is there another log or anything for the problem?

Comment: I am unable to compile  the code. Although i tried to change the  version also. Any other clue ?

Comment: Hi @Akshay_iOS Have you found any solution for this issue?